# How to Deserialize json string inside string in Java using Jackson - MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize a json string which is inside a string. I get this response and process it from Kafka from a different system so don't have a choice to change the publishing code. Extra Quotes is the problem but since its a message from different system, my input is fixed

```
@Data
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestModel {
    private Model model;
}

@Data
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Model {
    private String message;
}
```

Driver Code:

```
String t = "\"{\\\"model\\\":{\\\"message\\\":\\\"sample\\\"}}\"";
System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(t, TestModel.class))  //Exception
```

When the same String I try to deserialize as above I get the following exception.

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `test.TestModel` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"model":{"message":"sample"}}')
 at [Source: (String)""{\"model\":{\"message\":\"sample\"}}""; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1032)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1373)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:15)
```

Can someone please advise on this..

Comment: _"no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value"_ -- What do you think this means? Show us the code for `TestModel`.

Comment: You can't deserialize to an object - that's just a string as shown by the starting escaped quotation. Javascript is probably also returning a string when you parse that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this will work.

```
String t = "\"{\\\"message\\\":\\\"test\\\"}\"";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();
JsonParser createParser = factory.createParser(t);
JsonNode actualObj1 = mapper.readTree(createParser);
TestModel t11 = mapper.readValue(actualObj1.asText(), TestModel.class);
System.out.println(t11.getMessage());
```

Below is the TestModel class

```
public class TestModel {
    
    public TestModel() {
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you change the input string? The question states it cannot be modified

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have updated the answer, please check.